# ckeditor5 is missing button-icons

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm trying to use CKEditor 5 -- classic. It loads, but there are no button-icons in the tool bar -- just empty squares --- that work if you can guess the function!

I'm using CKEditor's example from this page:

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/react.html#quick-start

I'm using the default 'npx create-react-app testme', and replaced App.js with this (copy and pasted from their page):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h2>Using CKEditor 5 build in React</h2>
                <CKEditor
                    editor={ ClassicEditor }
                    data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
                    onReady={ editor => {
                        // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                        console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
                    } }
                    onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        const data = editor.getData();
                        console.log( { event, editor, data } );
                    } }
                    onBlur={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        console.log( 'Blur.', editor );
                    } }
                    onFocus={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        console.log( 'Focus.', editor );
                    } }
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

For completeness, here's my package.json:

```
  "name": "ckeditor",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^38.1.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^6.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```